# What is the difference between MapR and Map Reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, mapr

1. Is MapReduce the underlying algorithm for MapR or MapR FS?
2. Are the two terms related at all? If yes, please throw some light on the relation.
3. Is MapR related to Big Data?

Please be as detailed and as clear as possible in the answer.

MapR FS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapR_FS  .. MapR Converged Data Platform includes MapR streams + MapR JSON DB + Map R File System
MapReduce - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce
 MapR wiki page refers to Hadoop. MapReduce is sometimes referred to as Hadoop MapReduce and Hadoop is a popular Big Data framework. Therefore, I think both are related to Big Data.

Answer (score 2):

MapR is a business software distribution company that provides access to different Big Data workloads such as Apache Hadoop and Apache Spark.

MapReduce is a programming paradigm of Apache Hadoop. It was developed by Google.
MapReduce is the processing layer of the Hadoop architecture. It is based on master-slave topology. It divides a larger task into a number of smaller tasks and then executes them concurrently on different commodity hardware. It then clubs the results of these sub-tasks to obtain the final result.

Answer (score 0):

MapR is a software company. MapR-FS is a proprietary product they sell that is a replacement for HDFS, the Hadoop FileSystem

MapReduce is a general algorithm published by Google and also a programming API within Hadoop libraries. MapReduce can be used to process data in either HDFS or MapR-FS, as well as other systems